# why the design of user interface change in different emulator in android studio?

Tags: android

I'm begin to learning android programming and I did not know much about this language
I write a program. I do not know why when I see my user interface it is good but when I run it with different emulators , each emulator show it in different way

```
enter code here : <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context="com.example.faezeh.homework2.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView android:text="تمرین دوم"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="#ff4400"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="مدیریت یادداشت"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="تاریخ : 1393/12/26"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/theList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="فهرست یادداشت ها"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="جستجوی یادداشت "
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutUs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="درباره ما"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="تنظیمات"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: because each simulator has a different screen size and screen resolution

Comment: Check out : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: what i have to do to fix this? for example nexus one and nexus 5 show my program in different way . what i have to do to both of them show it in right way?

Comment: You have to design those interfaces for different screen sizes/densities. The appearence of elements in one screen device will for sure be different in another screen. Try to read more documentation about this on Android Devs.

Answer (score 0):

try to see this thing in your eclipse then your user interface will never change.
[image: see this pic below]

you can convert Activity check at here is schreen size 15 schreen sizes are given here to check all android device follow these size once

Comment: i did not use eclipse.i use android studio

Answer (score 0):

Since android is available for various types of devices, here I am saying the screen size of the device. So every device comes under certain category with their corresponding screen size, these category are probably **LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI and XXHDPI**. So the design we do usually varies among different screen size.

For detail information regarding the multiple screen size in android and how to handle it, do visit:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> what i have to do to fix this? for example nexus one and nexus 5 show
>   my program in different way . what i have to do to both of them show
>   it in right way? –  faezeh 1 hour ago

Well for this case you have to particularly design your screens in such a way that it optimize all the screen size. For this here are some key design parameters you should look on:

1. use textAppearnce instead of textSize property like :

   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
2. Try to hard code your controls specially buttons, as dp automatically resize according to the screen size of device.
3. Try to use layout_weight property in your design.

If you follow this basic guideline, then there will be no problem.

Cheers